# Is there any way to increase the number of collisions for my hashes for audio processing purposes?

Tags: python, audio-processing, hashlib

so I'm trying to make a bird shazam of sorts targeted towards Australian birds (as I haven't seen this here). Please don't tell me it's not going to work for real audio samples, I'm well aware of that and I'm just doing this for fun and to learn more coding :)

I've got this code so far (a lot of which I stole from the internet I will admit):

```
def hash_file(filename):
   """"This function returns the SHA-1 hash
   of the file passed into it"""

   # make a hash object
   h = hashlib.blake2s()

   # open file for reading in binary mode
   with open(filename,'rb') as file:

       # loop till the end of the file
       chunk = 0
       while chunk != b'':
           # read only 1024 bytes at a time
           chunk = file.read(1024)
           h.update(chunk)

   # return the hex representation of digest
   return h.hexdigest()

import os
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
list_of_sounds = {}

directory = r'Bird_Calls'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
        #print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        #print(hash_file(os.path.join(directory,filename)))
        hasha=hash_file(os.path.join(directory,filename))
        list_of_sounds[hasha] = [filename]
    else:
        continue

print(list_of_sounds)


import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "tmp.mp3"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()

recorded=hash_file("tmp.mp3")

if recorded in list_of_sounds:
    print(filename)
```

The problem is that when I record the audio (even if it's just playing a call I know is in the database and then just recording it to get the hash), the hash value is still different. I understand that this is due to slight offset in timing/audio quality/background noise etc. Is there a way to make my hash value "fuzzier" to increase the chance of a collision? Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way. Please don't point me in the direction of the dejavu program, I'm sure it works great but I want to see if I can code this on my own. Thanks!

Comment: You are calculating a secure hash of a file. This will never work. Increasing collisions is not what you need, because you don't want very different files to match randomly. You need a *predictable* hash of the sound which generates the same hash for similar data. Perhaps you should read a paper or watch an explanation of the Shazam algorithm on Youtube. It is *very* different from a cryptographic hash

Comment: Whether a hash is "fuzzy" is a property of how the algorithm was designed. You can't retune a cryptographic hash algorithm into a fuzzy hash algorithm; you need to design a hash algorithm that's fuzzy in the way you need, or use one someone else built. The former is doctoral-thesis level work, not a learning exercise for someone who hasn't spent significant time studying preexisting work in the problem domain (and probably quite a bit of math).

Comment: (and again, "in the way you need" is important; an algorithm built to hash similar-sounding English text into similar buckets will do no good at all when your input is audio recordings rather than text).

Comment: Where I would start, if this were my problem, is inspecting the FFTs of the specific bird calls, building a textual notation that can represent them, and building a transform from the FFT into that notation. Then you just need an algorithm to find the distance between two notations, which is a much easier problem; bucketing becomes just a performance optimization used to minimize the number of comparisons needed during processing, and you can defer it and implement after everything else works, if you have such a large corpus that you need it at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen Blake2S as the hash function. That's a cryptographic hashing function, which means it is designed to produce a very different result with every byte of input.

For you, that means: if your MP3 differs in just 1 byte, the resulting hash will be very different already.

Increasing the number of collisions does not help. Actually it will be opposite: any other file (even a text file, Word document or similar) would then have a higher change to match your bird song.

What you need is a hash function that is specifically designed for audio. For a Shazam-like functionality, that is:

- it can be relatively strict with timing, because we expect all playback to have the same speed (this could differ a bit due to manufacturing tolerances and temperature, but less than 1% probably)
- it must allow time shift, because recording may start sooner or later
- it can be relatively strict with frequencies, because it's recorded at a specific frequency and we expect the playback to produce similar results (this could differ if equalizers are used and every loudspeaker has different resonant frequencies)
- it must allow amplitude changes, because the playback can be louder or recorded from further away
- it must allow noise and environmental sounds

For birds, the algorithm becomes even harder, because

- it must allow timing differences, because not every bird sings at the same speed
- it must allow frequency shift, because birds may sing at a different frequency and they have nothing to tune

[image: Potential changes]

To get around some of the issues shown in the pictures, Shazam uses the spectrum instead of the waveform, so what you need is a fourier transformation (usually FFT, not many DFTs). And they don't do it once, but they do it in small increments, so they get a waterfall spectrogram, something like

[image: Spectrogram]

But they still need to consider that there is a time shift (shift on the X axis) and a difference in loudness (more intense colors). You additionally need to consider a shift and a stretch on both axes.

Maybe do something like image processing on the spectrogram. You could try to identify edges and regions with present frequencies and absent frequencies, like so:

[image: Feature detection]

That way you could say that both sounds contain 4 edges, 2 absent frequency areas and 4 present frequency areas as well as their relative position to each other are similar.

And that exactly needs to be your hash.